# How many Harriers crashed at or near MCAS Cherry Point?

Tags: military, accident-statistics, harrier, usmc

When I was stationed at [MCAS Cherry Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marine_Corps_Air_Station_Cherry_Point) in the late 1970's, we had a Harrier flip over and crash while practicing at the hover pad. It took off in the direction of our large hangar and thankfully went into the other side (depot maintenance) instead of ours (SOES) where we had a C-9B, T-39's and CH-46 aircraft, all fully fueled. I came back from lunch to find the Harrier in the parking lot at the other side of the hangar, after having plowed through what was left of another Harrier crash, among other things.

I was wondering. How many Harriers were lost in or near MCAS Cherry Point? Does anyone know?

Comment: [Related](https://youtu.be/esCe7qeOf6I?t=1150)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [List of Harrier Jump Jet family losses](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_Harrier_Jump_Jet_family_losses&oldid=1077135608) on Wikipedia, which appears to be derived from the Aviation Safety Network and is presumably accurate, 25.

Comment: I think it's 26, but wow, what a list.

Comment: There was one that was based there but crashed some distance away so I left that out.

Comment: That sounds about right.

Comment: The 1 May 1980 crash is the one I was talking about above. The description is not quite correct, the plane did not roll and then flip, but the rest of it, albeit generally described, is accurate. So many good Marines died. :( The only amusing fact about that crash is that the squadron sh*tbird at SOES got himself a medal for running to the other side of our hangar and being the first to fight the fires.